# using < > in a ASP.NET MVC Form causing problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a problem that seems like there should be a simple solution but haven't found it yet.

I have a pretty simple form that calls an action and passes it a FormCollection via HTTP Post.

The form works perfectly until I introduce `<` or `>` into the field.  Then I end up on a blank page having skipped the Action altogether.

Need more information?  Have any suggestions?  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate your action with `[ValidateInput(false)]`   attribute

Comment: Since this is going to be an internal application I may take this route but I am still curious and will explore the encoding route.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to encode these. [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) has a library that encodes a variety of ways (because encoding for HTML, URL, XML, attributes, etc are all slightly different)

If you want to turn off security (not a good idea if you care about security), [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) has an article on that, too.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  I have chosen the non-validation route at this time - since this is an internal app.  But I plan on exploring your route later down the line.  Thanks.